# Query m:n relationship for n = null - returns Lexer error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

Building a query to select M entities that have no corresponding N entities returns an error with the following query:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                        'SELECT p FROM VolVolBundle:Opportunity p '
                        . 'LEFT JOIN VolVolBundle:Volunteer v'
                        . 'WHERE v.id is null   '
                        . 'ORDER BY p.organization ASC'
                );
```

returns the error:

> Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'v'

Yet the following SQL statement returns a non-empty resultset:

```
select o.id from opportunity o
left outer join opportunity_volunteer ov on o.id = ov.opportunity_id
left outer join volunteer v on ov.volunteer_id = v.id
where ov.id is null;
```

where `opportunity_volunteer` is the linking table

#### Opportunity entity relationship definition

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Volunteer", inversedBy="opportunities", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="opportunity_volunteer",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="opportunity_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="volunteer_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      ))
 */
protected $volunteers;

public function addVolunteer(\Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Volunteer $volunteer) {
    $volunteer->addOpportunity($this);
    array_push($volunteers, $volunteer);
}

public function getVolunteers() {
    return $this->volunteers;
}
```

#### Volunteer entity relationship definition

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Opportunity", mappedBy="volunteers")
 */
protected $opportunities;

public function addOpportunity(\Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Opportunity $opportunity) {
    array_push($opportunities, $opportunity);
}

public function getOpportunities() {
    return $this->opportunities;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution was to create a 1:n:1 relationship, eliminating the "invisible" entity in the middle.  This enabled adding fields to the relationship.  So in addition to assuring each line ended with a space character before concatenation the query needed to be rewritten.  It now finds the null results as desired:

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM VolVolBundle:Opportunity p '
                . 'LEFT JOIN VolVolBundle:OpportunityVolunteerEmail e '
                . 'with p = e.opportunity '
                . 'where e.opportunity is null'
                . 'ORDER BY p.organization ASC'
        )->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the DQL [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), you should use WITH instead of WHERE to limit the join. Search for the code snippet "Restricting a JOIN clause by additional conditions" in the docs. I guess it should be something like:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM VolVolBundle:Opportunity p '
            . 'LEFT JOIN VolVolBundle:Volunteer v'
            . 'WITH v.id IS null   '
            . 'ORDER BY p.organization ASC'
    );
```

This is not tested, though.

Comment: I was unable to find any reference to using `WITH` in either a join or selection criterion, but your answer did lead me to find the (exceedingly dumb) mistake.  There needs to be a space following the v: `VolVolBundle:Volunteer v '`! I also learned that I need to return only the ids because the relationship chain is so complex. So an upvote for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: On relationship chain: the app uses PUGXMultiUserBundle in which Volunteer is a type of Person; the above query does not choke if the join is `LEFT JOIN VolVolBundle:Person`.  A query expecting two entities would crash using Volunteer and responds virtually immediately with Person.

Comment: I did eventually find a Doctrine reference on the use of `WITH` and included it in my answer.  The original problem - finding null cases - proved to be more of a challenge than expected. See the answer I've posted.